# How to name a Windows/NTFS VSS?

Tags: windows, vss

Is there a way to give a name to VSS (Volume SnapShot) into Windows?

The defaut name is like `@GMT-2017.02.12-15.52.45`.
I would like to give a specific name to some of them. Or at least to set some specific attributes to let them recognized by custom scripts (without record the names into a database, which is what we currently do).

I found nothing into the official documentation, nor with a search engine.